# Derivative of $X \mapsto \frac{AXA}{\operatorname{Tr} \left( AXA \right )}$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Given matrix $A$, I would like to compute the following derivative with respect to matrix $X$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X} \left(  \frac{AXA}{\operatorname{Tr} \left( AXA  \right)} \right) $$

I know that the derivative of the numerator is a fourth order tensor and the derivative of the denominator is a matrix, but I'm not sure how to combine them for the derivative of the quotient. Would you know how to do it?

Comment: Quotient rule still applies, especially moreso than usual since the denominator is a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\p{\partial}
\def\b{\beta}
\def\E{E_{k\ell}}
\def\F{F_{ij}}
\def\X{X_{k\ell}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 B &= AXA &\qiq dB = A\:dX\,A \\
\b &= \trace B &\qiq d\b = \trace{A\:dX\,A} \\
}$$
and the matrix $\E$ whose elements are all zero except for a ${\tt1}$
in the $(k,\ell)$ position.

Then the function of interest is
$$\eqalign{
F=\b^{-1}B
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
}$$
and its component-wise gradients can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
dF &= \b^{-1}dB - B\,\b^{-2}d\b \\
  &= \b^{-2}\BR{\b\:dB - B\:d\b} \\
  &= \b^{-2}\BR{\b\,A\:dX\,A - B\,\trace{A\:dX\,A}} \\
\\
\grad{F}{\X} &= \b^{-2}\BR{\b\,A\E A - B\,\trace{A\E A}} \\
\\
\grad{\F}{\X} &= \b^{-2}\BR{\b\,\LR{A\E A}_{ij} - B_{ij}\trace{A\E A}} \\
}$$
Note that there are *four* indexes, so the gradient is a fourth order tensor as you anticipated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had additionnal related questions; in order not to mess with this one, I opened a new topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499961/second-derivative-of-a-matrix-function